# How do items affect videos?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

Do the items in Tuber Simulator have to be in one room to affect the videos, or can they be in all three and still have the same effect? I want to move some items to the other rooms but I'm afraid that if I do then I'll lose views and subs on my videos since the items aren't all in my main room.

Answer (score 2):

Items affect videos by upgrading the related topics. For example, NES upgrades the "Gaming" topic. Each level of the topics gives more viewers and subs per video.

Therefore, you do not need to keep the items in the room to keep the bonuses provided by the items.